# How to find the client which is causing the stress or load on Cassandra service?

Tags: cassandra

I manage a Cassandra cluster used by Application developers. Recently there was a situation wherein Cassandra cluster is getting stressed at regular intervals (every 5 mins).

How do I find out which is the client (IP) that is causing the stress?

Answer (score 1):

A few options. You

- Can use `nodetool toppartitions` (profileload in future releases) during the period. profileload when available will help identify a few scenarios.
- Can use `nodetool settraceprobability 0.01` or some small % and look at the system_trace.sessions and events tables to see what queries are being executed.
- Can use `nodetool clientstats` to see the connected clients and the number of requests as well so if you look before and after the period you can probably work out which client is hitting you the most if its by request volume. If the client is sending large requests or querying for massive things (ie setting fetch size to 100000, selecting a lot of large blobs or something bad) it would be harder.
- Can also use tcpdump or wireshark - there are CQL dissectors available.

The issue may be GCs as well, which is ultimately more likely caused by a query hitting it every 5 minutes where you would want to do one of the above. But checking logs might help narrow that down right away (look for GCInspector). Looking at logs would be useful in identifying other things too like if the disk is blocking and causing mutations to backup and GC pressure for instance.

Comment: From the logs I figured out which keyspace and table is getting written a lot. But what I am not able to find out is which client is causing the stress. This is a shared cluster used by many developers. If there is a writes per sec or reads per sec at a per client level, it will help to identify the culprit.

Comment: In 4.0 you can use clientstats to find ip of one making most requests. you can probably figure out what table/partitions are getting written to still though if that would narrow down the person. If your seeing spikes in mutationstage that could be from disk too if the commitlog flusher is blocking them

Comment: I am using Cassandra 2.1.x. Hence don't have client stats option.